# Java mutex and Hibernate entity state

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, mutex

#### Test implementation

I'm running this piece of code in four threads parallel:

```
private volatile static boolean mutex = false;

private class Worker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        for (int i = 0; i < UPDATE_COUNT; i++) {
            plusOne(session, Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        session.close();
    }

    private synchronized void plusOne(Session session, long threadId) {
        while (mutex) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
        mutex = true;
        System.out.printf("thread-%d: mutex lock, begin, update\n", threadId);
        session.beginTransaction();
        MyEntity myEntity =
            (MyEntity) session.createQuery("from MyEntity").list().get(0);
        int oldValue = myEntity.getMyColumn();
        int newValue = oldValue + 1;
        myEntity.setMyColumn(newValue);
        System.out.printf("thread-%d: %d + 1 = %d\n",
            threadId, oldValue, newValue);
        System.out.printf("thread-%d: commit, mutex release\n", threadId);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        mutex = false;
    }

}
```

#### Output

Here's a sample output:

```
...
thread-17: mutex lock, begin, update
thread-17: 1 + 1 = 2
thread-17: commit, mutex release
thread-17: mutex lock, begin, update
thread-18: mutex lock, begin, update
thread-19: mutex lock, begin, update
thread-17: 2 + 1 = 3
thread-17: commit, mutex release
thread-18: 2 + 1 = 3
thread-18: commit, mutex release
...
```

The output varies due to thread scheduling.

#### Question #1: Java mutex (EDIT: Resolved)

```
thread-17: mutex lock, begin, update
thread-18: mutex lock, begin, update
...
thread-17: commit, mutex release
```

How can `thread-18` achieve that line between the two `thread-17` lines in a
synchronized method that uses the boolean variable `mutex` for deciding whether
the thread should be yielded or not?

Can you provide us with a proper way to implement mutex?

**EDIT:** See @Thomas' message below. The method `plusOne` is synchronized only within the Worker object. His suggestion `synchronized(Worker.class) { ... }` resolves the issue.

#### Question #2: Entity attribute value after commit (EDIT: Resolved)

```
thread-17: 2 + 1 = 3
thread-17: commit, mutex release
thread-18: 2 + 1 = 3
thread-18: commit, mutex release
```

How can `oldValue` be `2` on `thread-18` even though `thread-17` has committed
the value `3`?  Maybe it's because the Java mutex fails (Question #1) and both
threads can enter parallel the line `int oldValue = myEntity.getMyColumn()`
where the old value is read?

**EDIT:** This issue was caused by the Java mutex failure above.

#### Question #3: Entity state after Worker threads are ready (EDIT: Resolved)

This is how the threads are run and value asserted:

```
// Create one db row.
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
if (session.createQuery("from MyEntity").list().isEmpty()) {
    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
    myEntity.setMyColumn(0);
    session.save(myEntity);
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
// close here //

// Update the row simultaneously with multiple workers.
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < WORKER_COUNT; i++) {
    threads.add(new Thread(new Worker()));
}
threads.stream().forEach(Thread::start);
for (Thread thread : threads) thread.join();

// Check the result.
// open here //
session.beginTransaction();
MyEntity myEntity =
    (MyEntity) session.createQuery("from MyEntity").list().get(0);
assertEquals(WORKER_COUNT * UPDATE_COUNT,
    myEntity.getMyColumn().intValue());
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

After fixing the issues in questions #1 and #2 assertion still fails: `expected:<20> but was:<0>`

Why's that?

**EDIT:** I got this issue resolved by closing the initial session after the entity was created and opening a new one for the assertion. See the code block above. Replace

- `// close here //` with `session.close();`
- `// open here //` with `session = sessionFactory.openSession();`

#### Environment

- Debian Bullseye
- OpenJDK 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2
- Hibernate 5.6.0
- JUnit 4.13.2

#### Try yourself

See [this repo](https://github.com/haba713/hibernate_threads) for an easy way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The problem with your `plusOne()` method is that it's essentially not synchronized, i.e. synchronization happens on the  `Worker` instance and thus is not shared. You need to synchronize on something else e.g. add a `synchronized(Worker.class) { ... }` insicde the method.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. That resolved the issue. Can you check the new question (#3)?